# __typeof self in Objective-C generics?

Tags: objective-c, generics

Is this - or how is this - possible with the new Objective-C generics syntax?

```
@class MyHelperClass<T>;

@interface NSObject (Extension)
    @property (nonatomic,readonly) MyHelperClass<MYTYPE *> * helper;
@end
```

The question is:

What is the syntax for placeholder `MYTYPE *` - and does it exist - that would make this work with any subclass of NSObject. Meaning, that on a `UIView` instance, the `helper` property would return a `MyHelperClass<UIView *>` and on an `NSString` instance, it would return `MyHelperClass<NSString *>`? `__typeof self` does not work as `self` is not defined in an interface.

Suggestions are highly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this is possible. The most obvious way that I can think of to do this would be the following:

```
@interface NSObject (Extension)

- (MyHelperClass<instancetype> *)a;

@end
```

According to the clang documentation,

> `instancetype` is a contextual keyword that is only permitted in the result type of an Objective-C method

This is a compiler error, however, so perhaps the documentation should read "instancetype is only permitted *as* the result type of an Objective-C method."

My next thought was to cheat by writing some Swift code

```
protocol Test {
  var a: Array<Self> {get}
}
```

then importing it into an Objective-C file to see what the preprocessor did to turn it into Objective-C. Sadly, according to the [documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html), generics in Swift can't be accessed from Objective-C -- *because they aren't an Objective-C language feature!* This document has actually been updated for Swift 2.0, according to the revision history. Probably they still aren't supported because the Objective-C type system isn't as expressive as Swift's even with the currently available generics.

In summary, barring the existence of some obscure clang extension I don't know about, I think there's no possible way to do this.

Comment: Good answer. Really good. Thanks for the research. It just might not be achievable. :/

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answer, I don't think the language allows this kind of thing right now, just because it seems like it would be a rarely-used feature with many potential complications. I want to point out some type-safety issues with such a feature and inheritance.

If `MyHelperClass<instancetype> *` were the return type of a method, then it can only be safe if `MyHelperClass` were covariant with respect to its type parameter (i.e. if it were declared `@class MyHelperClass<__covariant T>`). This is because if a class `Foo` had such a method, it would also be inherited by any subclass `Bar`. Then when someone calls this method on a reference of type `Foo *`, they would expect a `MyHelperClass<Foo *> *` in return, but it might be a `MyHelperClass<Bar *> *` instead. It being `__covariant` means that a `MyHelperClass<Bar *> *` can be implicitly converted to a `MyHelperClass<Foo *> *`.

Analogously, if `MyHelperClass<instancetype> *` were a parameter type of a method, then it can only be safe if `MyHelperClass` were contravariant with respect to its type parameter (i.e. if it were declared `@class MyHelperClass<__contravariant T>`). Just like above, when someone calls this method on a reference of type `Foo *`, they can pass in a `MyHelperClass<Foo *> *`, but the method might expect a `MyHelperClass<Bar *> *` instead. It being `__contravariant` means that a `MyHelperClass<Foo *> *` can be implicitly converted to a `MyHelperClass<Bar *> *`.

This also explains why `instancetype` is allowed as a return type -- because a type is covariant with respect to itself.

The way you have declared it, with `@class MyHelperClass<T>`, means that `MyHelperClass` is invariant with respect to `T`, and thus it is neither safe to use `MyHelperClass<instancetype> *` as a return type nor as a parameter type.

Of course, all this is a moot point because the language doesn't allow something like `MyHelperClass<instancetype> *` right now; I am just pointing out what it would take to allow it.